# Angular 9 Curl request to companies house API : Collection 'companies' not found

Tags: angular, api, http, curl, authorization

Trying to make a companies house lookup via angular http. I've got a simple model to test the data, but I am not even getting an authentication error.

```
    {body: {…}, url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=BBC", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}
      body: {error: "Collection 'companies' not found"}
      url: "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=BBC"
      headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
      status: 404
      statusText: "Not Found"
      __proto__: Object
```

I'm using postman and the data is being returned there.

this is my test service:

```
 private httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
       Authorization: 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      })
 };

 private searchUrl = 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies?q=BBC'; 

 getCompany(): Observable<any>  {
    const url = `${this.searchUrl}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(url, this.httpOptions )
   ;
  }
```

Its not right I know. I don't know the return type so are using "any". I have scoured the interweb for an example but none found.

https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/index/gettingStarted/apikey_authorisation.html

This document says that:

> Basic authentication is usually made up of a username and password
>   pair; the Companies House API takes the username as the API key and
>   ignores the password, so can be left blank.

...so do I pass the api key in the header as a username?

any pointers humbly received

Comment: Can you console log the httpOptions object and see if the headers are set properly? I guess the way you are setting the HttpHeaders is wrong. The correct syntax should be: `new HttpHeaders({ fromObject: { ...your_header_entries...} })`

Comment: I don't think its getting that far. Its not throwing an unauthorised error.

Comment: I can't seem to get this working with Angular. If I use fetch it works fine.

Comment: I figured this out and its simple when you know... I was using the Angular InMemoryDataService to mock an API. This was causing the error. Its easily fixed if you come across the same issue... Add passThruUnknownUrl: true, to the object literal which is the second param in the forRoot clause of the  HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.